# Procurar componentes isoladas em grafo

Tags: algoritmo, grafo

Qual será o melhor algoritmo para encontrar componentes isoladas num grafo? Isto é, componentes que não perdem informação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesta imagem, a única componente isolada é a H, porque só recebe "informação".

Comment: Componentes isolados são os vértices que não têm arestas saindo para outros vértices?

Comment: @André Exato! Não há segredo. Deve-se iterar sobre todos os vértices. Para cada um, itera-se sobre todas as arestas. Se não houver nenhuma aresta ou o destino de todas as arestas for o próprio vértice, inclua-o no resultado. Por que não elabora uma resposta à pergunta?

Comment: Creio que [esse link](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos_em_grafos/aulas/componentes.html) deve ajudar a esclarecer o que é um "componente isolado" (Nota: pelo meu entendimento, segundo essa definição não há componentes isolados no grafo acima - exceto pelo grafo inteiro; talvez você quer dizer que a componente `H` é um **sorvedouro**?).

Answer (score 2):

Está difícil entender o que está sendo perguntado, pois tanto sua pergunta quanto algumas fontes que consultei usam nomes diferentes para o mesmo conceito, e vice-versa. Vou definir alguns termos, uns em português e outros em inglês mesmo, de acordo com o que pude entender:

- ***strongly connected component*** ("componentes fortemente conectados"): conjuntos de vértices em que cada um possui um caminho até o outro. Na sua pergunta, seriam os 4 conjuntos delineados (`{a,b,e}`, `{c,d}`, `{f,g}` e `{h}`).
- **sorvedouro** (*sink*): no caso de vértices, são vértices que não têm nenhuma aresta saindo dele, no máximo entrando; no caso de um conjunto de vértices, conjuntos em que nenhum vértice possui arestas saindo. No seu caso, o conjunto `{h}` é um sorvedouro. O vértice `h`, por outro lado, tem uma aresta entrando - aquela que sai dele próprio.
- **conjunto isolado**: um conjunto de vértices que é ao mesmo tempo uma fonte e um sorvedouro. Em outras palavras, conjuntos que não possuam arestas entrando nem saindo - apenas entre seus próprios vértices. No seu caso, não há conjuntos isolados não triviais (i.e. o conjunto vazio, e o conjunto de todos os vértices).

Se você já possui uma lista de *strongly connected components*, e quer saber quais deles são sorvedouros, faça como o @utluiz sugeriu nos comentários: verifique todos os vértices de um componente, se todas as arestas saindo levam somente a vértices no próprio componente. Se isso for verdade, esse componente é um sorvedouro. Se algum vértice no componente levar a outro fora do componente, então o componente não é um sorvedouro.

Se seu problema por outro lado for encontrar esses *strongly connected components*, aí já é mais complicado. Vou transcrever aqui (traduzindo livremente) o algoritmo proposto em ["Introduction to Algorithms"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033844), mas sem entrar muito em detalhes pois o conteúdo é bastante extenso.

```
STRONGLY-CONNECTED-COMPONENTS(G)

1. Chame DFS(G) para encontrar os tempos de término f[u] de cada vértice u
2. Faça a tranposição de G (Gt)
3. Chame DFS(Gt), mas no loop principal itere na ordem decrescente de f[u]
                                           (tal como computado no passo 1)
4. Os vértices de cada árvore na floresta do passo 3 são um strongly connected component
```

Caso você já tenha os tempos de término `f[u]` (na sua figura de exemplo, são os números dentro de cada vértice, depois da barra: `d[u]/f[u]`), basta chamar `DFS` no grafo transposto. não vou colocar aqui o algoritmo de transposição, pois deve ser trivial (é só inverter a direção de todas as arestas).

---

`DFS` é o [algoritmo de busca em profundidade](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos_para_grafos/aulas/dfs1.html). `d[u]` e `f[u]` são subprodutos desse algoritmo, mostrando a ordem em que cada vértice foi visitado (`d[u]` é o momento em que o vértice foi encontrado pela primeira vez, e `f[u]` o momento em que todas suas arestas de saída foram visitadas). Não vou transcrever o algoritmo do mesmo livro, pois o link acima dá uma implementação mais compreensível, em C++. Apenas vou adaptá-lo para incluir `f[u]`, já que o original somente contempla `d[u]` (lá chamado `pre`).

```cpp
/* Vamos supor que nossos digrafos têm no máximo maxV vértices. */
static int conta, d[maxV], f[maxV];

/* A função DIGRAPHdfs visita todos os vértices e todos os arcos do digrafo G.
   A função atribui um número de ordem d[x] a cada vértice x:  o k-ésimo vértice visitado
   recebe número de ordem k.  (Código inspirado no programa 18.3 de Sedgewick.) */
void DIGRAPHdfs( Digraph G) 
{ 
   Vertex v;
   conta = 0;
   for (v = 0; v < G->V; v++) 
      d[v] = -1;
   for (v = 0; v < G->V; v++)
      if (d[v] == -1) 
         dfsR( G, v);
}

/* A função dfsR supõe que o digrafo G é representado por uma matriz de adjacência.
  (Inspirado no programas 18.1 de Sedgewick.) */
void dfsR( Digraph G, Vertex v) 
{ 
   Vertex w;
   d[v] = conta++; 
   for (w = 0; w < G->V; w++)
      if (G->adj[v][w] != 0 && d[w] == -1)
         dfsR( G, w); 
   f[v] = conta++;
}
```

Alternativa para grafos representados por uma lista de adjacêcia (também adaptada):

```cpp
/* A função dfsR supõe que o digrafo G é representado por listas de adjacência.
  (Inspirado no programas 18.2 de Sedgewick.) */
void dfsR( Digraph G, Vertex v) 
{ 
   link a; 
   d[v] = conta++; 
   for (a = G->adj[v]; a != NULL; a = a->next)
      if (d[a->w] == -1) 
         dfsR( G, a->w); 
   f[v] = conta++; 
}
```

---

Se o passo 4 do algoritmo principal não está claro, a "floresta" que te interessa é formada por todos os vértices visitados em `DIGRAPHdfs`. Ou seja, se o primeiro vértice tem `d[u] = 0` e `f[u] = N`, todos os vértices que tem `d[u] > 0 e f[u] < N` fazem parte dessa árvore. A próxima árvore seria o vértice com `d[u] = N+1` e `f[u] = M`, e assim por diante até acabarem os vértices.

**Nota:** segundo a fonte citada, o algoritmo acima é eficiente (tempo linear em `V + A`) e embora não pareça está correto - a prova está em 4 páginas de teoremas que não vou transcrever aqui.