# Como checar se a função geraria um exit em C++

Tags: c++, funções, controle-de-fluxo

Tenho uma `.lib` com algumas funções. Defini que quando o calculo de alguma função gerasse valores fora do range permitido ela da um `exit()`.

Agora meu código em C++ que utiliza essa *lib* precisa calcular algumas dessas funções porém se a função que eu calcular no meio do caminho gerar um *exit* ele aborta e não calcula as outras. Existe alguma maneira de checar se retorna em um *exit* ou não, e se retornar pular a função?

Não tenho certeza se existiria um outro *flag* melhor para os valores fora do range permitido que não o *exit*. Eu tentaria um `return Null;` mas algumas dessas funções geram `vector<double>`

Qual seria então a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: A função `exit` retorna `EXIT_SUCCESS` ( Zero ) caso a execução tenha sido bem sucedida ou `EXIT_FAILURE` caso a execução tenha falhado, ambos retornos são macros. Você pode tratar o range de valores inválidos com um simples if / switch ( Switch com técnicas para cobrir ranges de valores em cada case ). Vale indicar o uso de `abort` no lugar de `exit` para que seu programa continue executando normalmente.

Comment: Tentar resolver esse problema me lembrou [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276746/64969) sobre o [problema da parada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/64969)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não tem como. O seu problema é outro.

O problema é de *design*. Se quer saber se a função conseguiu atingir seu objetivo ou não utilize uma forma de comunicação que indique isto, não utilize o [`exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit). Esta função deve ser usada para casos graves de problemas ou para o encerramento normal da aplicação em algum ponto onde se alcançou o objetivo e mais nada deve ser feito.

Existem várias técnicas para informar se a função deu certo ou não, no seu caso poderia usar uma exceção, ou algum [código de erro retornado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). Se o `nullptr` não atende, mas geralmente é adequada, tem outras formas citadas na pergunta *linkada*.

Inclusive testar se a função vai funcionar e depois usá-la tem potencial de gerar uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), não é a forma adequada.