# O que são "referências fracas"? Quando usá-las?

Tags: terminologia, independente-de-linguagem, referência, garbage-collector

Em ambientes de memória gerenciada, como Java, Python e JavaScript, eu já li algo a respeito de **referências fracas** (`WeakRef`). Li que tinha alguma coisa a ver com a detecção dos objetos que podem ser coletados, mas não ficou claro.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- o que é uma *referência fraca*?
- existe uma *referência forte*?
- quando devo usá-la?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As referências típicas e comuns entre objetos são fortes: Se o objeto A se refere ao objeto B por meio de uma referência forte, então o objeto B só poderá ser recolhido como lixo se o A também estiver sendo.

Já com as referências fracas, o funcionamento é diferente: Se o objeto A se refere ao objeto B por meio de uma referência fraca, então o objeto B pode ser coletado como lixo mesmo se o objeto A não puder ser.

A finalidade em usar-se referências fracas é basicamente uma só: cache. Por exemplo, imagine que na sua aplicação você mostre diversas fotografias que são lidas de arquivos e que frequentemente você esteja mostrando as mesmas imagens. Ocorre que ler de um arquivo sempre repetidas vezes é demorado e ineficiente, pois o acesso ao disco é lento. Por causa disso, convém manter essas fotografia todas na memória, evitando reler elas do disco. Entretanto, ao manter essas fotografias todas na memória, você poderá acabar consumindo-a por completo, sufocando outros processos em execução que precisem de memória. Assim sendo, você precisará de alguma forma de equilibrar isso, onde as fotografias sejam descartadas da memória quando puderem estar a atrapalhar outros processos.

É nesse momento que entram as referências fracas. Se você manter as imagens na memória por meio de referências fracas, elas ficarão lá enquanto não estiverem atrapalhando outros processos. A partir do momento em que faltar memória, antes que e o coletor de lixo lance um *out-of-memory*, ele irá tentar limpar algumas referências fracas para liberar memória suficiente. Nesse caso, a sua aplicação vai jogar fora da memória algumas das imagens armazenadas, que necessitarão ser relidas do disco se precisarem ser acessadas novamente.

O resultado é que a sua aplicação chegará a um equilíbrio onde poderá efetuar trocas de memória por desempenho de forma automática, gerenciada pelo coletor de lixo. Ela consumirá mais memória para ter um melhor desempenho e sacrificará esse desempenho quando precisar economizar memória.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta de Victor explica o que são referências fracas e 'fortes', mas eu nunca ouvi aquele sobre o cache com respeito as referências fracas.

A razão que uso referências fracas em C++ tem a ver com coleção e ciclos de referências. Por exemplo, se `A` tem uma referência a `B` e `B` tem uma referência a `A`, o programa nunca pode coletar a memória de `A` nem de `B`, porque os dois se referem.

Se `B` tem uma referência fraca a `A`, o programa pode coletar `A` quando não tem mais referências 'fortes'. Então pode coletar `B` porque a referência 'forte' dentro de `A` não existe mais.

Este tipo de ciclo de referências ocorre dentro de estruturas como listas duplamente ligadas.

C++ não tem um coletor poderoso e `std::shared_ptr` não resolve referências circulares.

Comment: Você está falando do que se chama de "referências circulares" ou "referências cíclicas". A maior parte dos garbage collectors sabe tratar casos disso de maneira adequada. Vida [a seção em que o @Maniero me menciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308679/64969)

Comment: @Jefferson, obrigado. Eu trabalho principalmente com C++ e uso `std::shared_ptr` quando quero coleção automática. Eu não sabia que os coletores mais modernos já resolveram este problema.

Comment: "A razão que uso referências fracas em C++ tem a ver com coleção e ciclos de referências. Por exemplo, se A tem uma referência a B e B tem uma referência a A, o programa nunca pode coletar a memória de A nem de B, porque os dois se referem" Não funciona, nem mesmo "forçando" coleta de memoria atraves de destrutores e uso de funcao como free e delete ?

Comment: @Rogi93, O propósito de usar `std::shared_ptr` é não precisar se preocupar com coleção de memória. Se precisar forçar a coleção, quer dizer que está usando as ferramentas de uma jeito errado.