# Quais as diferenças entre constantes declaradas com const e variáveis imutáveis declaradas com let em Rust?

Tags: variáveis, característica-linguagem, constantes, rust, imutabilidade

### A declaração de variáveis imutáveis

Em Rust caso queira declarar uma variável, usamos a palavra-chave [`let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.let.html).

Exemplo:

```
fn main() {
    let site_name = "Stack Overflow em Português";
    println!("{}",site_name);
}
```

Resultado:

```
Stack Overflow em Português
```

Esse tipo de declaração cria uma *variável imutável* que, ao ser alterada, levanta erros.

Exemplo:

```
fn main() {
    let site_name = "Stack Overflow em Português";
    println!("{}",site_name);
    site_name = "Stack Overflow em Português META";
    println!("{}",site_name);
}
```

Erros levantados:

```
error[E0384]: cannot assign twice to immutable variable `site_name`
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
2 |     let site_name = "Stack Overflow em Português";
  |         ---------
  |         |
  |         first assignment to `site_name`
  |         help: consider making this binding mutable: `mut site_name`
3 |     println!("{}",site_name);
4 |     site_name = "Stack Overflow em Português META";
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign twice to immutable variable

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0384`.
```

Ao executarmos `rustc --explain E0384`, é explicado que, por padrão, variáveis em Rust são imutáveis. Para corrigir esse erro, deve-se adicionar palavra-chave [`mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.mut.html) após `let` ao se declarar a variável. [Ver mais.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0384)

### A declaração de constantes

Rust também conta com uma palavra-chave especializada para a declaração de constantes, [`const`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.const.html).

Exemplo:

```
fn main() {
    const SITE_NAME: &str = "Stack Overflow em Português";
    println!("{}",SITE_NAME);
    
}
```

Resultado:

```
Stack Overflow em Português
```

Assim como ocorreu com o exemplo das variáveis imutáveis, a tentativa de retribuição de constantes irá gerar erros:

Exemplo:

```
fn main() {
    const SITE_NAME: &str = "Stack Overflow em Português";
    println!("{}",SITE_NAME);
    SITE_NAME = "Stack Overflow em Português META";
    println!("{}",SITE_NAME);        
}
```

Erros levantados:

```
error[E0070]: invalid left-hand side of assignment
 --> src/main.rs:4:15
  |
4 |     SITE_NAME = "Stack Overflow em Português META";
  |     --------- ^
  |     |
  |     cannot assign to this expression

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0070`.
```

Ao executar `rustc --explain E0070`, surge a explicação de que lado esquerdo de um operador de atribuição deve ser uma expressão de lugar. Uma expressão de lugar representa um local de memória e pode ser uma variável (com namespacing opcional), uma derreferência, uma expressão de indexação ou um campo referência. [Ver mais.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0070)

### A questão

Diante as informações reunidas acima eu pergunto:

**Em Rust quais as diferenças entre constantes declaradas com `const` e variáveis imutáveis declaradas com `let`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A palavra-chave `const` define uma constante. Por outro lado, `let` define uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/69296).

Sobre o local onde a declaração ocorre, constantes podem ser declaradas em qualquer escopo, incluindo o *top-level* (de módulos). Variáveis, contudo, limitam-se a blocos, como funções.

Em Rust, por padrão, qualquer variável (isto é, um *binding* definido com `let`) é imutável, o que significa que não pode ser alterada pelo programa. Contudo o programador pode, explicitamente, torná-la mutável sufixando a declaração `let` com o modificador `mut`, assim:

```
let mut name = String::from("SOpt");
```

Constantes, obviamente, não permitem o modificador `mut`. A própria declaração `const` já implica que o valor colocado ali há de ser imutável em quaisquer situação.

Uma constante é um nome opcional a qualquer [valor constante](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/constant-items.html), ou seja, o valor será *inlined* quando a constante for utilizada.

Já que constantes nada mais são que nomes a valores constantes, podem ser utilizadas em qualquer [contexto constante](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html#const-context). Variáveis, mesmo que imutáveis, não.

Durante a declaração da variável com `let`, é válida a omissão da anotação explícita do tipo em favor da inferência do compilador. Porém, ao se declarar uma constante, a declaração `const` exige que seu *binding* seja anotado explicitamente com o tipo de seu valor, mesmo que a inferência seja possível.

Sobre o tempo de vida, quando aplicável, variáveis podem ter qualquer [tempo de vida](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html). Constantes, todavia, sempre precisam ter tempo de vida estático, isto é, *lifetime* `'static`. Em alguns casos, esse tempo de vida pode ficar implícito pois há [*lifetime elision*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#static-lifetime-elision). Desse modo, ao anotar uma constante com, por exemplo, `&str`, o que ocorre, na verdade, é `&'static str`.

É interessante não confundir “valor imutável” com ”valor constante”. São coisas diferentes. Uma variável pode ser imutável ou mutável. Uma constante é sempre imutável.

---

Como Rust é uma linguagem compilada, há uma distinção importante a ser feita entre variáveis e constantes. O valor de uma variável pode ser determinado estaticamente ou dinamicamente (através de uma computação, por exemplo). Por outro lado, constantes podem apenas ser determinadas por mecanismos garantidamente estáticos.

Desse modo, você não pode definir uma constante cujo valor advém de uma computação qualquer (aqueles, por exemplo, que vêm de uma função). Essa limitação dá-se tendo em vista que, na maioria dos cenários, o compilador não possui condições para determinar se o valor de retorno de uma função é constante ou não. Há como relacionar essa limitação com o famoso Problema da Parada, já brilhantemente explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/69296).

A única exceção a essa regra são funções `const`. Isso significa que uma constante pode ser declarada com um valor que advém de uma [função constante](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html#const-functions). Isso ocorre porque esse tipo de função não é qualquer, uma vez que apenas um *subset* de valores de retorno são permitidos pelo compilador, tornando-o capaz de determinar se o valor retornado realmente é estático.

É importante também discutir sobre a forma como Rust trata constantes e variáveis em um nível um pouco mais baixo.

- A toda variável, associa-se um endereço de memória. Isso significa que todo valor de variável, imutável ou mutável, possui uma localização específica na memória do computador. Variáveis podem ser movidas e emprestadas (*moved* e *borrowed*, para quem estiver familiarizado com os termos em inglês).
- Constantes, por outro lado, não são armazenadas na memória, [pelo menos não de modo garantido.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/constant-items.html#:%7E:text=References%20to%20the%20same%20constant%20are%20not%20necessarily%20guaranteed%20to%20refer%20to%20the%20same%20memory%20address.)

  Na maioria das vezes, é interessante enxergar uma constante como um mero *alias*. É por isso que, no início desta resposta, citando o livro, disse que “uma constante é um nome opcional a qualquer valor constante”. Isso significa que, quando o código se referir à constante, seu valor será simplesmente copiado para lá, literalmente. Esse processo, que ocorre em tempo de compilação, é um tipo de *inlining*.

  Nesse sentido, isto:

  ```rust
  const SITE_NAME_ABBR: &'static str = "SOpt";

  fn main() {
      println!("{}", SITE_NAME_ABBR);
      println!("{}", SITE_NAME_ABBR);
  }
  ```

  Após o *inlining*, é mais ou menos isto:

  ```rust
  fn main() {
      println!("{}", "SOpt");
      println!("{}", "SOpt");
  }
  ```

  A necessidade de constantes serem estáticas, portanto, torna-se indubitável. Se o valor adviesse de uma computação não determinística, cada vez que a constante fosse consumida, um valor diferente seria produzido. Veja este exemplo absurdo:

  ```
  const INVALID_CONST: isize = random_int();

  fn main() {
      println!("{}", INVALID_CONST);
      println!("{}", INVALID_CONST);
  }
  ```

  Após o *inlining*, seria algo como o código abaixo. Não faz sentido substituir uma constante por uma função que pode retornar valores diferentes a cada chamada, tanto é que está errado ao ponto do compilador não permitir usar a referida expressão como constante.

  ```rust
  fn main() {
      println!("{}", random_int());
      println!("{}", random_int());
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: Variáveis imutáveis declaradas com `let` são apenas variáveis comuns, com a diferença que não podem ser alteradas ao longo do programa. Constantes, criadas com `const`, são um tipo completamente diferente, com várias outras propriedades, sendo imutabilidade apenas uma delas.

---

A diferença é que `let` cria uma variável e `const` cria uma constante. Parece óbvio, mas a diferença é importante, pois são dois tipos diferentes.

De acordo com o [livro oficial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/title-page.html) da linguagem, existem 4 diferenças entre constantes e variáveis, quais sejam:

**1.** *Você não pode utilizar a palavra chave `mut` em constantes.*

Como observado nos seus exemplos, constantes são *sempre* imutáveis

**2.** *O tipo da variável criada usando `const` sempre deve ser anotado, enquanto usando `let` você pode deixar o compilador inferir*

Por exemplo, o seguinte código falha em compilar:

```rust
fn main() {
    const a = 3;
}
```

Erro:

```
error: missing type for `const` item
 --> src/main.rs:2:11
  |
2 |     const a = 3;
  |           ^ help: provide a type for the item: `a: i32`
```

Se substituir `const` por `let`, funciona

**3.** *Constantes podem ser declaradas em qualquer escopo*

Por exemplo, isso funciona:

```
const NAME: &str = "stackoverflow";

fn main() {
    println!("{}", NAME);
}
```

Isso não:

```rust
let name = "stackoverflow";

fn main() {
    println!("{}", name);
}
```

**4.** *Constantes podem ser definidas apenas para uma expressão constante, não o resultado de uma chamada de função ou qualquer outro valor que só poderia ser calculado em tempo de execução.*

Para ilustrar essa última diferença, podemos aproveitar o exemplo anterior. Note que se declararmos a constante fora do escopo, não podemos usar uma função (que é conhecida só no tempo de execução). O código a seguir não compila:

```rust
const NAME: String = String::from("stackoverflow");

fn main() {
    println!("{}", NAME);
}
```

Simplesmente porque `String::from` não é conhecida no tempo de compilação.